# How can I unit test Resources File(.resw)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, localization, uwp, globalization

Good Day,

I implemented localization in my app, please see this links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/globalizing-portal

and this is how I did it in my app: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/862152/Localization-in-Windows-Universal-Apps

NOTE: I only add English language.

To unit test my .resw, My Idea is to get all keys from that , and check if each keys value is not null , how is that?

Thanks

Comment: That would be good as a check, but to verify whether correct values are displayed on UI or not you can have end to end automated UI tests for your application.

Comment: @IpsitGaur can you please elaborate more? Thanks

Comment: It would be good and extra for the Unit testing scope if you are doing localization checks as well, ideally, you should have Automated UI test cases like Selenium is used for web apps which checks UI and performs operations on that. Similarly creating an automation test suite for your app which checks localized text would be great.

Try google about UI automation tests for more info if you are not familiar with the term. Thanks

Comment: @IpsitGaur Okay , just saw an article about that , and it is different testing , lets just say I want to get all keys , how is that?

Comment: Not an answer, just an opinion: there is _little_ need for this kind of unit testing. The logic to get the resource by a key is rarely more than a few lines, and you rarely ever need to change that piece of code. It is either working all the time or fails in every case so you can find out and fix it right away. If the idea is for higher test coverage, then it is just not a good place to spend your effort.

Comment: @kennyzx okay , so youre saying I should not unit test my scenario , Automated UI test it instead? Thanks

Comment: Unit testing this is like writing a collection of string, and then asserting the elements of the collection is actually what you put...maybe not a good analogy, but the point is, there is little logic to test here. Unit testing is more focused on the parts where the code are more likely to change, and the parts with heavy logics that you need to assure expected values are returned for different inputs.

Comment: And I don’t have much experience in automated UI testing. I have tried CodedUI, it is like recording your input to generate testing scripts that can be repeated in later tests,  so it does not require the testers to input manually. In your scenario, I am not sure if it can help check if the translated literals are correct.